# How change url with react-router

Tags: reactjs, url, react-router, browser-history

I have some component

```
import { RouteComponentProps, withRouter } from 'react-router';
function MySearchComponent({ match, location, history }: RouteComponentProps) {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState<string>('');
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('all fine!')
    history.replace(`/my_search_page?query=${query}`);
  }, [query]);
  // some code for change query
}

export const MySearch = withRouter(MySearchComponent);
```

What's wrong? I'd tried to use `history.push`
console.log alter right when query changed, but nothing happend

UPD: Sorry. It was my mistake: my application just doesn't support search-parameters
Thanks for your help

Comment: console.log() is not called? Could yo put some more code? Are you sure that query changes?

Comment: Yes, it's called fine and yes query is changed

Answer (score 2):

In my application I am using useHistory hook

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const Operations = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    const res = prepareURLParams(filters);
    history.push(getRouterString("/", res));
  }, [filters]);
}

export default Operations;
```

Comment: @NachoZullo I was reading this article https://medium.com/@Charles_Stover/how-to-convert-withrouter-to-a-react-hook-19bb02a29ed6 and found this text "react-router's built-in withRouter HOC does not re-render components on route change, " Maybe this make sense...

Comment: Sorry. It was my mistake: my application just doesn't support search-parameters
Thanks for your help

Comment: @Dmitry What kind of application does not support query(search) parameters? Is it mobile application?

Comment: @Alexey My web-application is a tiny microservice worked in a large web application. I tried to change url on `/blah-blah-blah` without search-parameters and it's work fine. Looks like a search-parameters cutting from url in the base component